# UITableView cells not displaying all data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Populating the `UITableView` first from JSON file. Everything seems to be loading and there are no crashes but the table cells do not contain all of the data. They are cut off at the bottom.

HeroViewController

```
class HeroViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, WCSessionDelegate {

    // code

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return messageObject.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let tableCell : HeroTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell") as? HeroTableViewCell ?? HeroTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "MessageCell")

        let row = indexPath.row
        let rowObj = messageObject[row]

        tableCell.one.text = rowObj.title as String?
        tableCell.two.text = rowObj.speaker as String?
        tableCell.three.text = rowObj.from as String?
        tableCell.four.text = rowObj.to as String?

        return tableCell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your cells don't seem to have enough height. you can set it by over-ridding this method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100; //return the cell height you desire 
}
```